# Merging a menu without knowing about the parent menu?

Tags: c#, .net, menu, menuitem

I'm trying to figure out how auto-merging menus works. So far it seems like you have to know exactly what kind of menu the parent is going to have before you can define your child menu.

Ex: is there a way to have File -> Close that will show up on the parent both if the parent already has File -> Exit, *and* if the parent has no File menu at all? (and without duplicating the File menu)

In the former case I think you would use MergeActions MatchOnly and Append/Insert respectively for File -> Close, and in the latter case I think you would use Append/Insert for both. How can I setup the child menu to appear in either case?

That is, how can I get the child File menu to merge into an existing parent File menu, or append the File menu if the parent has no existing File menu?

If there isn't a way to do this in the editor, is there a way to do it with code? (Hopefully aside from writing my own recursive merging code.)

Thanks

Comment: Choosing the menu items properly will go a long way to solving this.  File + Close should be Window + Close.  File + Exit doesn't belong in a child window menu.

Comment: @Hans The names are merely placeholders; how do I get a child menu to *either* merge with an existing menu of the same name *or* append itself? The way it seems to work, the child form must be aware of the structure of the parent forms menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can conclude is that you cannot do this.